# Powershell Add Spaces to Registry Data Output

Tags: variables, registry, addition, spaces

I'm trying to create a small script, that can easily display some valid information to the standard user in regards of getting IT assistance from ServiceDesk.

[Current output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kpvVz.png)

So to improve this i was trying to figure out if i could add spaces to the teamviewer result.

This is an example of the current team viewer ID outcome:
1483547869

But i would like if the outcome could be:
1 483 547 869

This is a small thing but it will make it a lot easier to read for the standard user.

This is my code:

```
Add-Type -AssemblyName System.Windows.Forms
$ip=get-WmiObject Win32_NetworkAdapterConfiguration|Where {$_.Ipaddress.length -gt 1} 
$ipaddress = $ip.ipaddress[0]
$hostname = [System.Net.Dns]::GetHostName()
$TeamViewerVersions = @('10','11','12','13','14','')

If([IntPtr]::Size -eq 4) {
    $RegPath='HKLM:\SOFTWARE\TeamViewer'    
} else {
    $RegPath='HKLM:\SOFTWARE\Wow6432Node\TeamViewer'
}

$ErrorActionPreference= 'silentlycontinue'

foreach ($TeamViewerVersion in $TeamViewerVersions) {
    If ((Get-Item -Path $RegPath$TeamViewerVersion).GetValue('ClientID') -ne $null) {
        $TeamViewerID=(Get-Item -Path $RegPath$TeamViewerVersion).GetValue('ClientID')
    }
}

$msgBoxInput = [System.Windows.Forms.MessageBox]::Show("Computer Name: $hostname`nIP Address: $ipaddress`nTeamViewer ID: $TeamviewerID`n`nWould you like to open Self Service Portal?", 'Quick Support','YesNo','Information')
    If ($msgBoxInput -eq 'Yes' ){
    start https://www.google.com/

    Else 
 }

Stop-Process -Id $PID
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's a really simple solution to format a number:

```
$TeamViewerDisplayID = $TeamViewerID.toString("### ### ### ###")
```

This will display `1483547869` as `1 483 547 869`. Note: if your number will have 9 characters for example, the above line of code will add a space to the beginning. Example: `"483547869"` becomes  `"_483 547 869"`. So if you want, you can add another if statement there that checks how long the number is and formats it accordingly:

```
if ($TeamViewerID.length -gt 9) {
 $TeamViewerID.toString("### ### ### ###")
 } else {
 $TeamViewerID.toString("### ### ###")
}
```